# Checkbox boolean value Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I have a checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkNGI" id="prod_ngi_sn" value="1">
```

When it is checked I pass the value 1, but when it is not checked any value is passed.
I have to pass the value 0.

I've tried

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkNGI" id="prod_ngi_sn" <%if prod_ngi_sn.checked then value="1" else value="0" end if%>>
```

But didn't work.

tks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checkboxes only pass values when ticked. You need logic on the server side to accommodate that.

```
Dim chkNGI
chkNGI = Request("chkNGI") & ""
If chkNGI = "" Then
    chkNGI = "0"
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script> 
function calcParam() { 
  var checked = document.getElementById("prod_ngi_sn").checked; 
  if (checked) 
    document.getElementById("hiddenNGI").value = "1"; 
  else 
    document.getElementById("hiddenNGI").value = "0"; } 
</script> 

<input type="hidden" name="chkNGI" id="hiddenNGI"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="checkNGI" id="prod_ngi_sn" onClick="calcParam()">
```

Comment: I don't think this is the cleanest solution for classic ASP.

Answer (score 2):

Create a hidden input with the name "chkNGI". 
Rename your current checkbox to something different.
Add handled for onClick on the checkbox and using a small javascript function, depending on the state of the checkbox, write 0 or 1 in the hidden input.

As an example,

```
<script> 
    function calcParam() { 
        var checked = document.getElementById("prod_ngi_sn").checked; 
        if (checked) 
            document.getElementById("hiddenNGI").value = "1"; 
        else 
            document.getElementById("hiddenNGI").value = "0"; 
    } 
</script> 

<input type="hidden" name="chkNGI" id="hiddenNGI"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="checkNGI" id="prod_ngi_sn" onClick="calcParam()">
```

Comment: You just have to place the thml tags in the right place and the javascript section at the begining of the file.


`<script>
function calcParam()
{
var checked = document.getElementById("prod_ngi_sn").checked;
if (checked)
  document.getElementById("hiddenNGI").value = "1";
else
  document.getElementById("hiddenNGI").value = "0";
}
</script>

<input type="hidden" name="chkNGI" id="hiddenNGI">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkNGI" id="prod_ngi_sn" onClick="calcParam()">`

Comment: PS. Maybe `checked` is a reserved word for JavaScript. Instead of `var checked` use `var checkedState` to be sure.

Comment: Don't write code blocks in comments, add this to your post please.

Comment: Could you delete either this answer or your other one? They're identical, except this one adds some extra explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this single line solution

Information: RS=Recordset Object

```
<input type="checkbox" <%If RS("ColumnName")=True Then Response.Write(" checked='checked' ")%> name="tableColumn" value="1" >
```

Comment: I tried this, but the value of the checkbox is null when the control is not checked.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but I recently had to refactor some legacy code for a company in Classic ASP, and ran into this problem.  The existing code used a hidden form field with the same name as the checkbox and looked for either "false" or "false, true" in the results.  It felt kludgy, but the code also performed actions based on dynamically named checkbox fields with prefixes, so inferring "false" from a missing field would introduce different complications.

If you want a checkbox to return either "0" or "1", this technique should do the trick.  It uses an unnamed checkbox to manipulate a named hidden field.

```
<html>
<body>
<% If isempty(Request("example")) Then %>
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="example" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="example.value=example.value=='1'?'0':'1'">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<% Else %>
<p>example=<%=Request("example")%></p>
<% End If %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution in post to saving page;

**save.asp**

```
<%
' connection string bla bla
' RS = Recordset Object

If Request.Form("tableColumn")=1 Then 
    RS("ColumnName") = 1
Else
    RS("ColumnName") = 0
End If

' other columns saving process bla bla bla
%>
```